# Return promises javascript

Tags: javascript, function, return

How do I push the results from a promise to a outside array?? Like the exemple below. I want to be able to for exemple: console.log my title array and inf array.

```
var getCPU = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  cpu.totalLoad(function(error, results) {
    resolve(results);
  });
});
getCPU.then((results) =>{
 title.push(`CPU;`);
 inf.push(`${results};`);
});
```

Comment: Where do you expect to log the arrays?

Comment: My guess is the code is running fine, You just do not treat an asynchronous call as asynchronous.

Comment: I don't want to log, I want to use the ${results} value outside the promise

Comment: `return` `results` from existing `.then()` and chain `.then()` to use `results` within `Promise` chain. Though you could similarly use `results` in existing `.then()`.

Comment: If your arrays (title, inf) are global then you can use them anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
getCPU.then((results) =>{
 title.push(`CPU;`);
 inf.push(`${results};`);
}).then(()=>{
 console.log(title);
 console.log(inf);
});
```

Comment: But I don't want just to console.log I want to use the ${results} value outside the promise.

Comment: you can't, this async data, you have to wait until the info is available to play with it... otherwise, you are going to query something that is not there 'yet'... put it into a funcion, and call the function when you resolve the promise @RodolfoViola